# "curl" ignores proxy environment variable when using an ip address?

Tags: proxy, curl, openstack

I am using `curl` to access some web services through a proxy (an instance of `polipo` running on port 8123, chained to an ssh `SOCKS5` proxy).  If I provide proxy information using the `http_proxy` environment variable, it works just fine for requests using hostnames:

```
$ http_proxy=http://localhost:8123 curl http://overcloud-public-vip:5000/v2.0
{"version": {"status": "stable", "updated": "2014-04-17T00:00:00Z", ...
```

The name `overcloud-public-vip` isn't resolvable locally, but it can be resolved by the remote proxy to 192.168.30.6.  If I try using the ip address of the target host instead of the hostname, it fails:

```
$ http_proxy=http://localhost:8123 curl  http://192.168.30.6:5000/v2.0/
```

On the other hand, the same url works just fine if I use the `-x`
command line option instead of an environment variable:

```
$ curl -x http://localhost:8123 http://192.168.30.6:5000/v2.0/
{"version": {"status": "stable", "updated": "2014-04-17T00:00:00Z", ...
```

Why is there different behavior when specifying the proxy using a
command line option vs. specifying the proxy in the environment?  Is that a
bug, or am I missing something?

Comment: I can't get to the bottom of this and I can't test it, but the examples I have found specify `export http_proxy=...` on one line and `curl ...` on the next. Does this work the same as using `-x`?